# When I convert to upper case azure-powershell command is not working as expected

Tags: azure-powershell

In azure pipeline I have to give $env = prd in small letters as its being used by many othe tasks. But actual resoucrce group names look like rg-e2-PRD-703. SO I have given below commands but its not giving me output

```
## $env =prd is given in pipeline
$environment = "$(env)".ToUpper()
write-host $environment ## its printing PRD as expected
$getNIClist = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -clike 'rg-*-$environment-*' | Select-Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command as below:

```
$aa = 'rg-*-' + $environment + '-*'
$getNIClist = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -clike $aa} | Select-Object
```

or you can also change the `'` to `"`:

```
$getNIClist = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -clike "rg-*-$environment-*"} | Select-Object
```

because escape will not be done in single quotes

Hope it helps~